# d3 make a individual bar Chart of week and Hours between and set the Item in the right Position

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, svg, d3.js

I am working on an Bar Chart with D3.js and im absolutely new to it.

**I have two Problems**

**Problem 1:**
i want a Bar Chart which X-Axis has different weeks (6 Week in the Future) and each Week betweens
have 40 Hours see the Graphic:

[image: barChart Example]

**Problem 2**

How can im later Implement 3 Orders which Timeline its need in the Bar Chart in the right Positions:

- Order 1: Begin at: Week 46 and 39 Hours
- Order 2: Begin at: Week 45 and 43 Hours end into Week 46
- Order 3: Begin at: Week 45 and 126 Hours end into Week 48

I tried some and have parse successfully the Weeks and Order with the following Json data array but cant :

**PHP:**

```
//Hours
$hours = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40);
//Weekdays
$week = array(
        0 => array("week" => 45,
                   'hours' => $hours
                ),
        1 => array("week" => 46,
                    'hours' => $hours
                ),
        2 => array("week" => 47,
                    'hours' => $hours
                ),
        3 => array("week" => 48,
                    'hours' => $hours
                ),
        4 => array("week" => 49,
                    'hours' => $hours
                ),
);

$json_weekdays = json_encode($week);
$json_hours = json_encode($hours);
$json_plannedOrder = json_encode($plannedOrder);
```

**Javascript**

```
var weekdays = <?= $json_weekdays; ?>;
let hours = <?= $json_hours; ?>;
var data = <?= $json_plannedOrder; ?>;

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50, right: 50},
    width = 1050,
    height = 500 - (margin.top - margin.bottom);


var svg = d3.select("#dashboard-order")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)");

// Scale the range of the data in the domains
var xScale = d3.scalePoint()
    .domain(weekdays.map(function(w){
            return w.week;
        })
    )
    .range([0, width])
    .padding(0);

var yScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(data.map(function(d){ return d.Order.order_id }))
    .range([0, height])
    .padding(1);

// Bars anzeigen
// append the rectangles for the bar chart

svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate("+ xScale( d.Order.week ) +",0)"; 
    })
    .attr("width", function(d) { 
        return xScale( d.Order.hours ); 
    } )
    .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.Order.order_id); })
    .attr("height", "50");

//append X Scale
svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisTop(xScale))
    .attr("transform",  "translate(0," + margin.top + ")");

//append Y Scale
svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisRight(yScale))
    .attr("transform",  "translate(0," + margin.top + ")");
```

What would I need to do to, to show the Hours Between the Weeks and set the Order in the right place that Planned for the Week with Hours?

Comment: Please ask one question per question, otherwise, if someone can answer only one part, they might not feel comfortable answering the whole. Also, please turn your code into a [mre], with some sample data. See also [ask]!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the Solutions i have changed the Structure and have make each Week 40 Hours in them e.g.

n(Weeks) * 40;

so D3 know which Point the Bar must go in the X-Axis i changed the Week array into this Structure:

```
0: {isAWeek: 1, weekCalender: "45", hour: 0}
1: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 1}
2: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 2}
3: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 3}
4: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 4}
5: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 5}
6: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 6}
7: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 7}
8: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 8}
9: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 9}
10: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 10}
11: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 11}
12: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 12}
13: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 13}
14: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 14}
15: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 15}
16: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 16}
17: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 17}
18: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 18}
19: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 19}
20: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 20}
21: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 21}
22: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 22}
23: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 23}
24: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 24}
25: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 25}
26: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 26}
27: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 27}
28: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 28}
29: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 29}
30: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 30}
31: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 31}
32: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 32}
33: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 33}
34: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 34}
35: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 35}
36: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 36}
37: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 37}
38: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 38}
39: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 39}
40: {isAWeek: 1, weekCalender: "46", hour: 40}
41: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 41}
42: {isAWeek: 0, hour: 42}
....
```

with this Structure i can mark Which Hour is a new Week and can define in the X-Scale when he hit this Data with isAWeek == 1 he display the Week and continue the Hours Point:

```
//append X Scale
svg.append("g")
    .call(
        d3.axisTop(xScale).tickFormat( function(w, i) {
            if( weekdays[i].isAWeek == 1 ) {
                return weekdays[i].weekCalender;
            } else {
                return "";
            }  
        })
    );
```